# Best way to work with Java projects using Maven and Eclipse with embedded Tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, maven, eclipse-wtp

I've run non-Maven applications on an Eclipse embedded Tomcat server before and I found the instantaneous deployment upon saving invaluable. However after starting a Maven project I didn't find any easy way to continue doing this.

Using WTP and the Dynamic Web Module Project Facet seems to wreck the project's Maven nature. Using JRebel is not possible in our company. Googling didn't provide any results that would work without again removing the project's Maven support. Is there any other way or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Install m2elipse with WTP extension. Import your Maven WAR project. m2eclipse will configure Eclipse for and your can continue using your Tomcat in WTP.